# How do I find out why my webpage doesn't finish loading?

Tags: javascript, html, django-1.7

I'm making a little webapp for reasons, and while everything seems to load just fine, the tab throbber keeps throbbing, as though it hasn't finished loading the page. Why? How can I debug this? The Network tab in Chrome's dev tools makes it look like everything's loaded, but it JUST WON'T STOP SPINNING, AAAAA.

[image: Screenshot]

I'm using Django 1.7, but I don't *think* that's relevant to the question...maybe it's debug server is a bit wonky, but I'd think this is just maybe some script (which...how to find out) that's irritating me.

Comment: The problem is that the term `SECRET_KEY` is visible on your screen. This causes Chrome to send a screenshot to Google, which can take a while.

Comment: @lxg plz don't hax `http://localhost/` :(

Comment: `chrome://net-internals`

Comment: Is that the Google Loader jsapi.js?

Comment: FWIW, I have a similar issue with Django 1.7, running on Windows server 2012

Answer (score -1):

There are certain items on your page that might continually monitor. For example we have a live chat service that is technically always doing a type of polling in the background. I've noticed some browsers Firefox in my example, act like the page is continually loading when it's not, but technically is. Optimizly is another service that runs continually in the background. Do you have any of these services or anything third party?

Comment: I'm using jQuery (by way of Bootstrap), but that is find for many other people, so why me? My question is how can I debug it?

Comment: Looking in the Network in Firebug generally works. Any iframes on the page? Just loading jQuery wouldn't hold things up. I've seen Google Analytics do strange things sometimes.